# Is it legal to take input from String[] args AND standard input in the same program?

Tags: java

To my understanding, it would not be legal because a program can only take one of the two forms of argument input at a time. However, I'm not 100% sure about my answer however, so if anyone would be able to clarify, it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What happened when you tried it?

Comment: Could you show an example code?

Comment: It's not based on code I'm writing. I'm just asking out of generality if its legal or not. I could still show you code if that were to help.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is legal. Command line arguments have nothing to do with characters read from the standard input.

For example this code works perfectly fine:

```
public class Example {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Printing command line arguments: ");
        for(String s: args) {
            System.out.println(s);
        }
        System.out.println("Printing from standard in: ");
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        while(sc.hasNext()) {
            System.out.println(sc.next());
        }
        sc.close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No problem with that. Each running program (in Windows and Unix/Linux based OS alike) has:

- A "current" work directory
- Arguments it was started with
- Environment variables (most often inherited from the parent process)
- An input stream
- An output stream
- An error stream

It can work with these at its own discretion (with obvious limits like not being able to modify the arguments or write to input stream).

---

Where some confusion may come in is in comparison with a [Servlet](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnafe.html) and its handling of requests - the request may be read as a byte array, as stream or through some framework that translates it into an object model or maps it to parameters. This situation is however different, because the HTTP request indeed only contains one stream of data (I'm leaving out headers for simplicity), so you have to choose which approach to use and cannot use both at the same time.

The situation is different with a pure Java process and its `main()` method, since the arguments and the input stream are different pieces of data, not merely different ways to look at the same data.